# Why should I inherit?

Tags: c#, oop

Sorry if this is a foolish question, but i m very much confuced

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string property1 { get; set; }
        public void method1()
        {

        }
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
       public void method2()
       {
           property1 = "set from  Class2";
           method1();
       }

    }

    public class Class3 
    {
        Class1 objClass1 = new Class1();
        public void method3()
        {
            objClass1.property1 = "set from  Class3";
            objClass1.method1();
        }

    }
}
```

If i can access all public methods of Class1 from Class3 by using object of class1,
What s the advantage of inheritance (as done in Class2) ?

Comment: You're asking for a computer science class.

Comment: Inheritance or Association depends on your usage scenario.

Comment: Half-serious: There is no advantages really in case you've shown... You can't really change behavior of `Class1` as it have no virtual methods and you used up the only base class possibility you have in C#... Common interface may  work better in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`In OOPs, the concept of inheritance provides the idea of 
reusability. This means that we can add additional features 
to an existing class without modifying it.
This is possible by deriving a new class from the existing 
one. The new class will have combined features of both the 
classes.`

- Once a behavior (method) or property is defined in a super class(base class),that behavior or property is automatically inherited by all subclasses (derived class).
- Code reusability increased through inheritance.
- Inheritance provide a clear model structure which is easy to understand without much complexity Using inheritance, classes become grouped together in a hierarchical tree structure Code are easy to manage and divided into parent and child classes.

Answer (score 1):

the advantage of inheritance is that class2 exhibits all the properties and methods of class1.
you can access methods of class1 by using object of class2.